# Installing MySQL database on Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, database, windows-services

I need to install MySQL on Windows XP. But looks like both .msi and and .zip versions require Windows admin rights to get database working. Is there any way possible to install MySQL without windows admin rights?
If not, is there any database that doesn't require installation(NOT an in memory database)?

Comment: EasyPHP comes with it all.

Comment: personally i'd install WAMP as i like an easy life although you will need admin rights for this too - http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Comment: @f00, I had never heard of WAMPServer; when I saw your comment, I automatically thought you said [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), until I saw the page. `>.<`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zip does not require any administrative rights, if you do not run database as a service.
you can run it from the command line, , e.g with

bin\mysqld --console

after unpacking the zip.

Comment: Agreed. Only *installing* requires admin rights because it gets installed and run as a service. You can still run the daemon like any other background program without admin rights. (Though whether it can act as a server, open and listen on a port, and receive data without admin rights is another matter. It may work, but I for one haven’t tried it… though I’d be interested in hearing if it does.)

Comment: It can act as server, and open and listen to port, even if user running it is not administrator. Whether or not one can connect to this port from another machine, is subject of firewall rules (and also mysql's own authentication rules)

Comment: I tried this but got the following error: `mysqld: Could not create or access the registry key needed for the MySQL application to log to the Windows EventLog. Run the application with sufficient privileges once to create the key, add the key manually, or turn off logging for that application`

Comment: @user32882 you are right. i too get the same message. i don't know how others aren't getting it while executing without admin rights. did you make it work?

Answer (score 2):

- MySQL is installed to run as Windows Service so you need Admin rights or rights to install services on your computer.
- You can try SQLite is a file based Database.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get away with installing MySQL without admin rights, because it's a service.

If you can't get around that, give [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) a try. It's file-based, can be just unzipped to any directory and drivers exist for most languages.